# Using Enterprise Library to log to a custom Windows event log does not work

Tags: .net, logging, windows-7, event-log, enterprise-library-5

I have configured the Enterprise Library 5.0.505 Logging Application Block to log events from my .NET 4 application to a custom windows event log. 'Custom' meaning that the log is application-specific and shows up as an entry under the "Applications and Services Logs" in the Windows 7 Event Viewer MMC snap-in. I have followed the steps in the [logging application block documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664639%28v=pandp.50%29) to configure  this correctly, including setting up the custom log, but the events are being logged to the default Application log instead. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Turn it off and on again". Windows seems to need restarting after creating a custom event log. After doing this, the log entries are saved in the custom log as expected.